# Get the version number from <xs:schema in a xml schema while unmarshalling with JAXB

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb, schema, unmarshalling

I have a xml schema:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs=... version="1.0">
```

How can I get the version number after unmarshalling with JAXB?

I have tried using this:

```
<xs:element name="schemaVersion" type="xs:string"/>

<xs:element name="echoSchemaVersion">
    <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
             <xs:element ref="schemaVersion"/>
         </xs:sequence></xs:complexType></xs:element></xs:schema>
```

I am missing a way to connect my element to the version value in

Comment: Is there a way to access the version number in the root element?

Comment: I guess there is something not really clear. You have an XSD schema version but you are working on XML (based on a certain schema) during unmarshalling. So you don't have that information.

Comment: No I have a xml schema with a version number <xs:schema... version="1.2.3">. After the schema gets unmarshalled with JAXB or converted to a Java file, I want to be able to know the version number of this schema (getSchemaVersion())

Comment: You mean you want to compile a xsd, and get the version from the java file ? if so it is not possible, it is not included in the code generated.

Comment: I am trying to pass the schema version into the java code after being unmarshalled with JAXB for verification. I do not think there is an easy way to do that

Comment: What is the purpose of getting the version?

Comment: A custom unmarshaller should be able to do whatever?

Comment: I am getting the version for future validation of schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this could be a solution.

I made the schema version as a constant after unmarshalling by adding it as an attribute

```
<xs:attribute name="schemaver" type="xs:string" fixed="1.2">
<xs:annotation><xs:appinfo><jx:property fixedAttributeAsConstantProperty="true"/>
</xs:appinfo></xs:annotation></xs:attribute>
```

I also had to add the jx:version="2.1" in the schema root element.